# how to create an app which monitors what ip's my android phone access ?

Tags: android

I'm not sure how to phrase the title of the question.
But the question is pretty simple, there is an app called openVpn for android (which allows a user to connect to vpn server).

I don't want the user to open the app when he want's to access my service, i want it to be seamless, meaning : when some app tries to access my service IP address, i want to catch that event, load openvpn and only then allow the user to access my service.

I wrote few android apps, but never something like this, where do i start ? 
Is it possible to monitor where other apps are going (to which IP address) without rooting the device ?
Maybe some kind of driver ?

I searched around the web, and couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In a unrooted device, you shouldn't be able to monitor the connections made by other apps and in fact, you can't.

As an workaround, I guess you can just launch OpenVPN from you app (if OpenVPN registers itself for any Intent). So, the user doesn't have to remember about it.

Else, you have no more choice than integrating OpenVPN inside your app (the source code, I mean) or just telling your users that they have to launch it.